# What are object Names of of Python Console ToolBars?

Tags: qgis, qgis-python-console

I have a custom plugin that when loaded it hides all tools and toolbars not specified to load. How ever by doing this it hides all the tools that are present in the python console. Clean Console, Show editor, save script, run script etc. I have tried in many ways to track down what are the names of these toolbars so i could specify them to load with my plugin but just cannot find them. I am referring to the tool bars in the photo. Can anyone help me track these down?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Andrew! Perhaps the following link might help: [https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/console/console.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/console/console.py)